# How to update tag value with the slider updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

Basically I am trying to [implement this](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-html5).

This is my HTML:

```
        <td>
            <p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-r-sm" id="slider-step-value">5</button>
              Speed
            </p>
            <div id="basic_slider_1"></div>
        </td>
```

This is how I initialized 4 sliders on my page:

```
$("#basic_slider_1, #basic_slider_2, #basic_slider_3, #basic_slider_4").noUiSlider({
    start: 3,
    step: 1,
    behaviour: 'tap',
    connect: 'upper',
    range: {
        'min':  1,
        'max':  10
    },
    pips: {
      mode: 'steps',
      density: 1
    }
  });
```

So what I want to happen is, as the value generated by `basic_slider_#` (where `#` can be `1, 2, 3 or 4`), it should update the value of the `slider-step-value` that is related to that `basic_slider_#`.

How do I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/3rnwpbwv/3/)**.

I think that what you looking for :

```js
var sliders = $('.slider');
var buttons = $('.slider-step-value');

for ( var i = 0; i < sliders.length; i++ ) {
  var button = $(sliders[i]).prev('p').find('button')[0];
  
  noUiSlider.create(sliders[i], {
    start: 3,
    step: 1,
    behaviour: 'tap',
    range: {
      'min':  1,
      'max':  10
    },
    pips: {
      mode: 'steps',
      density: 1
    }
  });
  
  attachEvent(sliders[i], button);
}

function attachEvent(slider,button){
  slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {
    button.innerText = parseInt(values[handle]);
  });
}
```

```css
.slider .noUi-origin {
 background: #c0392b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/8.2.1/nouislider.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-r-sm slider-step-value">5</button>
  Speed
</p>
<div class="slider"></div>
<br><br>
<p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger m-r-sm slider-step-value">6</button>
  Speed
</p>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

Comment: I guess the main question i will ask is, how do I select the `slider_step_value` that is closest to the currently manipulated `basic_slider`? There are multiple `div.slider-step-value`

Comment: _how do I select the slider_step_value_ What you mean by _select_ ?

Comment: Meaning, make sure that the correct value is updated. In other words, in your example, if you duplicated the entire `p` tag, would it work correctly? I doubt so, because all `div#slider-step-value` would update. To be fair, an ID should be applied to just 1 element, but you can interchange that with `class`. The idea is that I want the button that is closest to the `basic_slider` to be updated, not every other `button` on the page.

Comment: Updated for the last time to be efficient and target the button inside the previous `p` using `$(sliders[i]).prev('p').find('button')[0]`.

Comment: For some reason, I am getting this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined`.

Comment: Try please to use the same version that i've in the snippet.

Comment: Interesting...ok so trying the version you have does work better, but it still has some issues. For starters, it has the scale below the slider, which my original version didn't. How do I get rid of that? Also, is there a version of `nouislider` that is hosted on a stable, reliable CDN rather than on the creators domain? In other words, it now looks like this: http://imgur.com/a/J6D1x -- but I want to get rid of the marks at the bottom.

Comment: Ok nvm re: the marks. I figured out that if I remove the `pips` section, it takes care of that. How about the CDN hosted version?

Comment: Ok i see, in fact yes check the the cdnjs version : https://cdnjs.com/libraries/noUiSlider

Comment: Version 8.2.1 looks fine check : https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/3rnwpbwv/1/, i've updated my post to this version.

Comment: That `cdnjs.com` link works like a charm. I found a hosted `9.0` which works perfectly. Thanks much meng. This really helped me out!

Comment: One last question, how do I make the sliders be green on one side and white on the other? Right now, everything is white.

Comment: It turns out to be an option in `nouislider`. All I had to do was do `connect: [true, false],` within the `nouislider.create` call and it worked like I wanted it. Thanks though!

Comment: Any experience with Rails by any chance? I have a related issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334682/how-do-i-convert-this-js-snippet-to-default-to-rails-info-rather-than-the-defaul